# Android Studio Apache functions

Tags: java, android, apache

I've been trying to create `DefaultHttpClient object` with:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

but I'm unable to find this class can't be resolved in my Android Studio.
After googling this class, the first result shows the following URL:[Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html)

and it's `404: not found page.`

Does anyone know how I can use this function and similar function such as HttpGet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use urlconnection. If i remember correctly, defaulthttpclient is deprecated.

```
URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
```

Comment: urlconnection is an abstract class

Comment: Edited the answer to reflect what I meant.